# Scrolling elements into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

On scroll, I am adding a class (`current`) to particular elements.

The code looks like it can be made better. For example, it seems like I am reusing the same things over and over again (i.e. the `nth-child(1)`, `nth-child(2)`, etc.).

I appreciate any and all comments and advice.

```
 function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    if (elem.length > 0) {
      var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
      var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
      return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
  }

   $(document).scroll(function () { // Measure scroll To Top
      // @TODO Fix it so that there is only 1 if block
      if (isScrolledIntoView($('.section .main-content:nth-child(1)')) === true) {
        $('.events-widget-menu li').removeClass('current');
        $('.events-widget-menu li:nth-child(1)').addClass('current');
      }

      if (isScrolledIntoView($('.section .main-content:nth-child(2)')) === true) {
        $('.events-widget-menu li').removeClass('current');
        $('.events-widget-menu li:nth-child(2)').addClass('current');
      }

      if (isScrolledIntoView($('.section .main-content:nth-child(3)')) === true) {
        $('.events-widget-menu li').removeClass('current');
        $('.events-widget-menu li:nth-child(3)').addClass('current');
      }

      if (isScrolledIntoView($('.section .main-content:nth-child(4)')) === true) {
        $('.events-widget-menu li').removeClass('current');
        $('.events-widget-menu li:nth-child(4)').addClass('current');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try `$('.section .main-content').filter(function() {
    return isScrolledIntoView($(this));
}).last().addClass('current');` in `ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why `:nth-child` selector is even in play here.  It seems all you are wanting to do is add a class to an `li` with same index within its parent as what the content's index within it's parent is.

I might suggest something along these lines to achieve that:

```
// Cache jQuery collections somewhere in scope that `scroll()` inherits.
// This prevents you from having to continually re-query the DOM every time
// there is a scroll event.
var $mainContent = $('.section .main-content');
var $eventLi = $('.events-widget-menu li');

$(document).scroll(function () {
    $eventLi.removeClass('current');
    // find content elements in view
    var $currentElements = $mainContent.filter(function(index) {
        return isScrolledIntoView(this);
    });
    // apply class to LI with corresponding index
    $currentElements.each(function() {
        var index = $mainContent.index(this);
        $eventLi.eq(index).addClass('current');
    });
}
```

This solution is not hard-coded to X number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      var curElem = $('.section .main-content:nth-child(' + i.toString() + ')');
      if (isScrolledIntoView(curElem) === true) {
        $('.events-widget-menu li').removeClass('current');
        curElem.addClass('current');
      }
    }
});
```

I didn't test it, but that should be it.

Comment: Without a declaration for `i` using `var` or `let` a global variable would be created, which won't lead to an error but typically [frowned upon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/244085)